# React Query hook call from orval

Tags: react-query

I use orval to create interfaces, services and it also create React Query hooks. I have a hook that I cant figur out how to use. It wants some UseMutationOptions togheter with my data.

```
export const useGetUserContext = <TError = ErrorType<unknown>, TContext = unknown>(options?: {
  mutation?: UseMutationOptions<
    Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getUserContext>>,
    TError,
    { data: UserContextRequest },
    TContext
  >;
  request?: SecondParameter<typeof customInstance>;
}) => {
  const { mutation: mutationOptions, request: requestOptions } = options ?? {};

  const mutationFn: MutationFunction<Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getUserContext>>, { data: UserContextRequest }> = (
    props,
  ) => {
    const { data } = props ?? {};

    return getUserContext(data, requestOptions);
  };

  return useMutation<Awaited<ReturnType<typeof getUserContext>>, TError, { data: UserContextRequest }, TContext>(
    mutationFn,
    mutationOptions,
  );
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by post hook?

Comment: Just a hook that does a post not a get

Comment: You should be using a query for this, not a mutation (unless your api call creates some change in the backend state)

Comment: Orval creates the code (hooks) to use. So I cant edit them